# Method ignores the first duplicate element in list and prints the rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

I'm calling a sorted linked list into the `duplicates_sorted` method, it then ignores the first duplicate in the list and prints the rest. Why isn't it including the first duplicate?

Unsorted - 1, 13, 65, 78, 12, 25, 1, 2, 13, 39, 13, 48, 10, 2
Sorted - 1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 25, 32, 39, 48, 65, 78

prints: 2, 12, 13

I pass an unsorted list into the `bubble_sort` method and have it sorted. Then I pass that list into the `deuplicates_sorted` method.

```
class Node(object):
    item = -1
    next = None

    def __init__(self, item, next):
        self.item = item
        self.next = next

    def has_next(self):
        return self.next!=None
    def get_next(self):
        return self.next
    def set_next(self,node):
        self.next=node


class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.item=None
        self.size=0

    def length(self):
        curr = self
        total = 0
        while curr.get_next() is not None:
            total +=1
            curr = curr.get_next()
        return total

    def get_next(self):
        return self.item.get_next()

    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item, self.item);
        self.item = new_node;
        self.size += 1;


    def print_list(self):
        print("Print List = ", end= "");
        if self.item is None:
            return;
        current = self.item;
        print(current.item, end=", ");
        while current.get_next():
            current = current.get_next();
            if not current.has_next():
                print(current.item, end="");
            else:
                print(current.item, end= ", ")

# method that makes problems:
    def duplicates_sorted(nums):
        k = nums
        duplicate_elements = []
        while k is not None:
            if k.get_next() is None:
                break
            if k.item == k.get_next().item:
                duplicate_elements.append(k.item)
            k = k.get_next()
        print("Duplicates: ", duplicate_elements)

def bubble_sort(num):
    for i in range(num.length()):
        m = num.item
        n = m.get_next()
        while n is not None:
            if n.item is None:
                break
            if m.item > n.item:
                swap(m, n)
            n = n.next
            m = m.get_next()


def swap(node1, node2):
    temp = node1.item
    node1.item = node2.item
    node2.item = temp

def single_list():  #merges two txt files into one
     merge_list = LinkedList() #create empty linked list
     with open('file1.txt', 'r') as myfile: 
        for line in myfile:
           merge_list.add(int(line.strip()))
        myfile.close()


     with open('file2.txt', 'r') as myfile: 
        for line in myfile:
            merge_list.add(int(line))    
        myfile.close  
     return merge_list

def main():
    #creating a linked list
   bubble_sortlist = single_list() #prints unsorted list
   bubble_sortlist.print_list()
   print()
   bubble_sort(bubble_sortlist) #prints sorted list
   bubble_sortlist.print_list()
   print()
   duplicates_sorted(bubble_sortlist) #prints duplicates

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is `k.get_next()` doing?

Comment: getting the next item in the list, that line is supposed to compare an element with the element beside it

Comment: ... dont name variables `list` - that is the name of a built in and your variable definition shadows it ...

Comment: sorry didn't know about that, i edited it

Comment: Let me include more code

Comment: Can you please include the code used to initialise your list and run the commands that give you problems?

Comment: Please [edit] your question again and add the definition of `single_list` so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I included the  _single_list_

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the first `Node` and `LinkedList` objects:

```
>>> lst = LinkedList()
... for value in reversed((1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 25, 32, 39, 48, 65, 78)):
...    lst.add(value)
...
>>> duplicates_sorted(lst)
Duplicates:  [2, 12, 13]
>>> duplicates_sorted(lst.item)
Duplicates:  [1, 2, 12, 13]
```

The problem is that both `Node` and `LinkedList` implement `get_next` and `item`. However, `LinkedList.item` returns a `Node` whereas `Node.item` returns a raw value.

That means `duplicates_sorted` is defined for both, but only makes sense for `Node`objects. If `k` is the `LinkedList`, the following compares a value against a `Node`:

```
k.item == k.get_next().item
# ^                    ^ 1
# \ Node(1, ...)
```

If you want `duplicates_sorted` to be a method, unpack the first element already:

```
class LinkedList:
    ...
    def duplicates_sorted(self):
        k = self.item  # unpack first item
        ...
```

If you want both types to be valid, you should make sure that `duplicates_sorted` unwraps depending on input type:

```
def duplicates_sorted(num):
    k = num.item if isinstance(num, LinkedList) else num
    ...
```

Comment: I understand now, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have an error inside your duplicates_sorted. The error fixes itself after the first element, hence no reproduction of your error if the first 2 elements are no dupes but reproduceable if first 2 elements are dupes.

Fix:

```
class LinkedList(object):

    # ... snipp ... 


    # instance method of LinkedList
    def duplicates_sorted(self):   

        k = self.item                # this is the first item of self, NOT self itself.
                                     # self itself would be a LinkedList()
        duplicate_elements = []
        while k is not None:
            if k.get_next() is None:
                break
            if k.item == k.get_next().item:
                duplicate_elements.append(k.item)
            k = k.get_next()
        print("Duplicates: ", duplicate_elements)
```

Test:

```
L = LinkedList()
for n in [1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 25, 32, 39, 48, 65, 78]:
    L.add(n)
L.print_list()
L.duplicates_sorted()

L = LinkedList()
for n in [1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 25, 32, 39, 48, 65, 78] [::-1]:
    L.add(n)
L.print_list()
L.duplicates_sorted()
```

Output:

```
Print List = 78, 65, 48, 39, 32, 25, 13, 13, 12, 12, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1
Duplicates:  [13, 12, 2, 1]

Print List = 1, 1, 2, 2, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13, 25, 32, 39, 48, 65, 78
Duplicates:  [1, 2, 12, 13]
```

As non-instance method:

```
def duplicates_sorted(ll):    
    k = ll.item                 
    duplicate_elements = []
    while k is not None:
        if k.get_next() is None:
            break
        if k.item == k.get_next().item:
            duplicate_elements.append(k.item)
        k = k.get_next()
    print("Duplicates: ", duplicate_elements)
```

Comment: That was the problem, Thank You!